# Método document.adoptNode() - HTML - JS

Tags: javascript, html

Preciso desenvolver um página que mostre o funcionamento do método adoptNode(), pelo o que eu li ele basicamente remove um nó de uma página externa e carrega para o documento atual. Esse é meu código, mas o elemento de tag H1 não é carregado pra página atual:

```html
<html>
<body>
<!-- Carrega página com um elemento de tag H1  -->
<iframe src="ex2.html" style="height:380px;width:520px;"></iframe> 

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

   

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var frame = document.getElementsByTagName("IFRAME")[0];
    var h = frame.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName("H1")[0];
    var x = document.adoptNode(h);
    document.body.appendChild(x);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```